# Understanding [options] argument in Backbone.sync method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascript-objects

I'm working on `BackboneJS` project and I need to override Backbone.sync

I was looking for code example and I found this.

```
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
   options || (options = {});
```

I want to know what is the meaning of `options || (options = {});` here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of that line is to ensure that the `options` hash is a hash object and not `null`. More generally, this is one way in JavaScript to give a parameter a default value.